# Handling dblclick event in Konva

Tags: javascript, konvajs, konva

I am trying to perform various operations in case of mousedown, mousemove, mouseup, click and dblclick event. Like i use mousedown event to initialize a rectangle, and on mousemove i want to expand that rectangle shape, on mouseup it will finish drawing rectangle shape.

On click event, i want to select the shape using konva.transformer.

Now what i noticed when i want to select the shape, i use click, and this also trigger the mousedown and mouseup event. When i want to use dblclick, it actually trigger the click, mousedown, and mouseup events.

How can i stop propagating the events and avoid this conflict ?
When i click, it should only execute the click event.

I tried using e.evt.stopPropagation(), e.cancelBubble but none of them worked.

Comment: If my answer helped please mark it as the correct answer. This helps future users who are searching for similar questions.

Comment: You can see in my comment that e.cancelBubble was not working for this case.

Comment: Make a demo that shows the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
evt.cancelBubble = true;
```

See https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Cancel_Propagation.html